# concatenate string inside sql recursive WITH statement CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i'm trying to concatenate the values from a column from all levels of a certain path

this is my sql:

```
WITH
hi as (
select c.id id, cast(c.code as nvarchar) code, c.title, c.parent from CaseTypes c 
where c.parent is null

union all

select c.id, cast((h.code + c.code ) as nvarchar) code , c.title, c.parent from CaseTypes c 
inner join hi h on c.parent = h.id
)
select * from hi
```

the problem is that only the first level (where parent is null) is taken, the rest isn't

Comment: I just ran your exact code on a test table and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code will concatenate the string and only display the last parent

```
declare @CaseTypes table (
    code nvarchar(max),
    title varchar(20),
    parent int, id int
)

insert @CaseTypes values ('a', 't1', null, 1)
insert @CaseTypes values ('b', 't2',    1, 2)
insert @CaseTypes values ('c', 't3',    2, 3)

;with hi as (

    select c.id id, cast(c.code as nvarchar) code, c.title, c.parent 
    from @CaseTypes c 
    where c.parent is null

    union all

    select c.id, cast((h.code + c.code ) as nvarchar) code, c.title, c.parent
    from @CaseTypes c 
    inner join hi h on c.parent = h.id
)

select id, code, title, parent 
from hi h 
where not exists (
    select 1
    from hi
    where h.id = parent
)
```

Comment: Not really much change, but sometimes the problems we are faceing are hard to spot.

Comment: it's no change at all actually, but at least I know that the problem is in something else

Comment: there is a change, I picked the right row. I was assuming your code only picked one of the rows from the result

Comment: my problem is in the concatenation, in your example if doing select * at the end you will get for code a, ab, abc (3 rows) as with my table i get just 'a' (code of the first parent) for all the rows

Comment: I took your exact code and tried, I get a,ab,abc with your exact code. I think you should take a look at your id and parent for your data, I bet the problem is there.